# How to find all monomials $\left\{\left.x^n\in P_m\right|T(x^n)=0\right\}$ and which are in $\text{ker }T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Let $P_5$ be the set of one variable polynomials with real coefficients, whose degree are $\leq5$. Let $T$ be a linear transformation $\left\{\left.T:P_m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\right|f(x)\mapsto\int_{-1}^{+1}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right\}$.

---

How would I find all monomials $\left\{\left.x^n\in P_m\right|T(x^n)=0\right\}$?

I'm thinking I have to use a matrix of the form

$$$$\begin{pmatrix}1&x_1&x_1^2&\cdots&x_1^{n-1}\\1&x_2&x_2^2&\cdots&x_2^{n-1}\\1&x_3&x_3^2&\cdots&x_3^{n-1}\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\1&x_m&x_m^2&\cdots&x_m^{n-1}\end{pmatrix}$$$$

i.e. a Vandermonde Matrix. I think the solution follows from that discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1270541/basis-of-ker-t-for-mathcala-left-en-cdot-x-mid-n-in-mathbbz-right); in general, we know that a $5\times5$ matrix, if $$\nu(t)=\det\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1&1&1\\x_0&x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4&t\\x_0^2&x_1^2&x_2^2&x_3^2&x_4^2&t^2\\x_0^3&x_1^3&x_t^3&x_3^3&x_4^3&t^3\\x_0^4&x_1^4&x_2^4&x_3^4&x_4^4&t^4\\x_0&^5x_1^5&x_2^5&x_3^5&x_4^5&t^5\end{pmatrix},$$

$\Rightarrow\nu(x_0)=\nu(x_1)=\nu(x_2)=\nu(x_3)=\nu(x_4)=0\\\Rightarrow\nu(t)\text{ is some polynomial of degree 5 with a coefficient }\left\{\left. k \text{ on }t^5\right|k=\displaystyle\prod_{4\geq\ i>j}(x_i-x_j)\right\}$

---

I'm having a lot of trouble doing two things:

1. Moving from the general Vandermonde matrix to this specific case;
2. Showing that $\det(V)$ is the matrix associated with $$\left\{\left.T:P_m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\right|f(x)\mapsto\int_{-1}^{+1}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right\}(\textbf{and if this is, in fact, accurate}).$$

---

Does $\nu(x_5)=\displaystyle\prod_{4\geq\ i>j}(x_i-x_j)$ span $\text{ker }T$? How would I go about explaining why this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

We have two cases:

- $m$ is odd. Then $T(x^m) = 0$ by simple integration.
- $m$ is even. Then $T(x^m) > 0$, since $x^m$ is positive on $[-1, 1]$ except for at $0$.

Comment: So $T(x^n)=0 \iff n\equiv 1 \;(\bmod\; 2)$? And these all span $\text{ker }T$?

Comment: *Yes* to the first, *No* to the second. When we restrict $T$ for example to the span $V$ of $x^2$ and $x^4$ then $V$ will intersect with the kernel non-trivially by rank-nullity theorem. The polynomial $5x^4-3x^2$ is in the kernel but not in the span of the the odd powers of $x$.